# Add values from one dictionary to another after making operations on those values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe. I want to group the dataframe by 2 columns, get the length of the dataframe slices and then add the length to another dictionary, using the first part of the key, meaning "C".

My code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C': [20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 30, 30, 30],
                   'C2': [20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10, 10, 30, 30, 30],
                   'D': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})

df_dictionary = df.groupby(["C", "C2"])

second_dict = dict()

for key, df_values in df_dictionary:
    print(len(df_values.index))
```

I have tried the following:

```
for key[0], df_values in df_dictionary.iteritems():
    second_dict.setdefault(key, []).extend(df_values.index)
```

But it does not let me perform operations on the df_values. Is there some way I can go around this? In the end, the second dictionary should have the following values

Comment: What is expected output from sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), remove second level by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `drop=True` with [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.groupby(["C", "C2"]).size().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).to_dict()
print (d)
{10: 3, 20: 4, 30: 3}
```

If need values of index:

```
d1 = (df.groupby(["C", "C2"])
        .apply(lambda x: x.index.tolist())
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .to_dict())
print (d1)
{10: [4, 5, 6], 20: [0, 1, 2, 3], 30: [7, 8, 9]}
```

Your solution should working:

```
for key, df_values in df_dictionary:
    second_dict.setdefault(key[0], []).extend(df_values.index)

print (second_dict)
{10: [4, 5, 6], 20: [0, 1, 2, 3], 30: [7, 8, 9]}
```